# Key exchange protocol and digital signatures

Tags: encryption, signature, diffie-hellman, key-exchange

I am a beginner to coding and encryption standards... I have this task assigned in a course I am following:

- Design and implement a key exchange protocol. Include digital signatures in the protocol for authentication.

Does implementing the Diffie-Hellman algorithm covers both parts as in key exchange and digital signature or only the key exchange part? If so what should I do?

Is there any other approach on covering both parts?

Comment: Look into the "Station to Station" protocol -- it is an authenticated key agreement protocol.  Basically, the messages are signed, which doesn't happen with "basic" D-H.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Diffie-Hellman key exchange protocol by itself does not include any use of digital signatures.

However, Diffie-Hellman is also insecure against man-in-the-middle attacks, because the messages are not authenticated. This should give you a pointer what to do with the digital signatures.

Comment: Of course, there are protocols which replace signatures with special DH exchanges ;)

Comment: @SEJPM Which doesn't exactly help when you are specifically asked to use signatures now, does it? :D

Comment: guys can anyone please explain what is to be done to solve this ?